# Using the data returned from [matDatepicker] of Angular Material to append to POST call

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-material2

I have this HTML that is from Angular Material

```
> <mat-form-field class="start-date-full-width">   <input matInput
> [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Start Date">  
> <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix
> [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>   <mat-datepicker
> touchUi="true" #picker></mat-datepicker> </mat-form-field>
```

And I need to set the data given to me to **dispStartTs** from when I pick the actual date [heres the data I'm talking about](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZSTG.png)

To my TS file.

Here's the code I have so far:

```
  onUpdatePingIt() {
    let dispMsg = this.pingItMessageForMessageCenter + ' ' + this.pingItMessage;
    let dispStartTs = this.startDatePicker;
    let dispEndTs = '';
    let userId = ;

    this.apiEndPointService.onUpdatePingItMessageBoard(dispMsg, dispStartTs, dispEndTs, userId).subscribe(response => {
      console.log(response)
    });

  }
```

How can I go about doing this? Any help would greatly be appreciated.
I'm assuming I will need to make a separate TS file or maybe even a service and manually pick it and just re use in the component. But I could be wrong. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question right, you have to use [formControl] directive. Here is an  [example](https://stackblitz.com/angular/aalyjxxlajnn?file=app%2Fdatepicker-value-example.html)  from  [material help page.](https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview)